# how to convert sql to linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

using ef4

iam trying to convert this sql to linq but could not

```
select s.IdSimcard ,s.Imei from dbo.SimCard s 
where s.Imei  not in (select distinct d.Imei  from dbo.SimCard d  inner join dbo.Configuracion c
on c.SinCard_IdSincard = d.IdSimcard
where c.Estado = 'Activo' )
```

So far I have this with the help of linqpad, I cant use linquer anymore for the activation code

```
(from s in SimCard where  s.Imei.Contains( (from c in Configuracion
                             join d in SimCard on c.SinCard_IdSincard equals d.IdSimcard
                             where c.Estado == "Activo"
                             select new { d.Imei }).Distinct())
                             select new {  s.IdSimcard, s.Imei })
```

I have read "Not in" dont supported in EF4, what woul be the equivalent?

i get this error in linqpad

*'string.Contains(string)' 
  - Argument 1: cant convert de 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'*

Comment: try this: http://www.sqltolinq.com/  sorry, i'am tired today :-)

Comment: cant use anymore my trial version expired :(

Comment: from s in SimCard
 where ! (from c in Configuracion where c.Estado == "activo"
        select c.SinCard_IdSincard).Contains(s.IdSimcard)
 select new { s.IdSimcard, s.Imei}

ok, It look this will do :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can use the `Except(...)` Extension method (in the System.Linq namespace) instead of `Not Contains(...)`.